# C# getter vs readonly

Tags: c#

Is there any difference between the following?

```
class C
{
    // One:
    public static readonly int ValueAsAMember = 42;

    // Two:
    public static int ValueAsAProperty { get { return 42; } }
}
```

I'm used to writing constants the first way (unless they're private/internal, in which case I use the const keyword), but I recently saw the second form.

Is there any advantage one way over the other in terms of readability, convention, performance, or anything else?

Comment: This is probably not a good question for SO. But I'll give an answer anyway: use `const`, which is more or less equivalent to your first line. The second line introduces a method call, which will probably be inlined anyway, but what's the point?

Comment: Why don´t you use "const"?

Comment: The only usage I have of `readonly` is when I set them in constructors, typically interfaces for TDD and designmode(WPF & SL). Use `const` in this example and C# naming standard, not c/c++  hehe ;)

Comment: @Crasher `const` is replaced at compile time in the IL. Let's say you have two assemblies, A and B, and Assembly B references Assembly A's const value. If you change the `const` value in Assembly A, but don't update Assembly B with a newly-compiled version, you can have weird behavior where the value is different between the two assemblies. It's definitely an edge case, but it's something to consider when designing a public API, for example.

Comment: siride - Why would this not be a good question for SO?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is an advantage:

If the value gets changeable at any point in the future (e.g. in a future version of your code), in a way that it is, for example, time-dependent, you can support that in the read-only property without changing the public interface of your class.

If you have to replace a `readonly` field with a property, you will have to recompile any other assemblies that use your class.

Comment: but please remember that `readonly` field can be changed only in `constructor` of `class`

Comment: @harry180: Sure, wouldn't claim otherwise. That's why I mentioned that the `readonly` field would have to be replaced with a property in the described case.

Comment: Great point; I didn't think about this. I appreciate the thoroughness of pescolino's answer as well as Daniel Mann's response to others regarding the const keyword. I purposely didn't ask about const for that exact reason because it wasn't part of the discussion. Thanks to everyone for their answers!

Comment: Just a remark: In the case of `readonly`, if you want to change the value in the future with another *static* value, you'll still be fine and won't need to recompile other assemblies.

Comment: Agreed, but I never thought about the time-dependent part--that appears to be the only discriminator between the two, even though it seems like it might be a rare oddity to start with one and later transition to the other.

Comment: I'd say it a disadvantage that you can change it without recompiling. what if other assemblies use it like `var cache = SomeExpensivePureFunction(C.Value)`?

Comment: @adrianm: Why should they? It is simply not guaranteed that a property will always return the same value.

Comment: That is exactly my point. A readonly property has a disadvantage bacuase it is no longer readonly in the same way a field is readonly. i.e. a readonly property can't be used in a pure method and you need to consider if it is safe to use from multiple threads.

Comment: This seems like such a tiny difference to justify the existence of the two different concepts in the language. C# is definitely not designed to be simple...

Comment: @MarcosPereira: I disagree that difference is "tiny". In a patch, it can mean the difference between providing just a new version of a single assembly vs. also providing possibly considerable numbers of other files that reference the patched assembly. Likewise, in a development context, the difference can be that of compiling just your changed assembly vs. also compiling plenty of other solutions that reference your assembly.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I would just never use public fields in C#, and instead rely on automatic properties when the logic is simple, manual properties when it is complex.

Comment: @MarcosPereira: I agree, but IMHO the only tangible reason why one should cling to the principle of never using public fields is exactly what I described. As for auto-properties, note that getter-only auto-properties didn't exist yet when this question and its answer were written.

Answer (score 38):

You have three choices:

- `public static readonly int Value = 42;`
- `public static int Value { get { return 42; } }`
- `public const int Value = 42;`

Choose `static readonly` if the value will not change at runtime but might change in future versions of your code.

Choose a property if the value might change at runtime. Of course it won't change if you use the given code.

Choose `const` if the value is really a constant that will not even change in future versions (something like `Math.PI` or `int.MinValue`). And of course the use of `const` is limited by the type of the value.

The difference between `const` and `static readonly` is that the `const` value will be replaced on the call site. If you change the value of a `const` in a future version then all assemblies that rely on your class need to be recompiled using the new value.

The property requires a method call (calling a getter is a method call). So if the value is constant at runtime there is no need for that.

Comment: "which means: don't choose it for a constant value" Er, why not?

Comment: @BenAaronson: Basically because I thought there would be some overhead for the method call. But rethinking it I just realized that the call will be inlined. I Removed that doubtful advice. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: +1 for the "will not even change in future versions" part. Too many programmers forget about that condition. -1 for the "property requires a method call" part, since the compiler can optimize that out.

Answer (score 9):

There are two major differences:

The first is that fields cannot be on interfaces, whereas properties can. So if you want to use this in an interface, you have to use the property.

The second, more interesting, is that `readonly` fields CAN be modified, while the object is being constructed. Take the following code:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public readonly int MyInt = 1;

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        MyInt = 2;
    }
}
```

If a caller does

```
new MyTestClass().MyInt
```

they will get 2. The same goes for static constructors for a static `readonly` field.

Comment: +1 for mentioning interfaces. Useful for decoupling implementations.

Answer (score 3):

The way I see it, using the first way describes the intention of the value better - which is that it is immutable. When a person is looking at the class' interface, he will see that the value is read-only, and won't have to wonder whether it can be changed later (since in the second case he can't see the property's implementation).

An important thing to note about `const` declarations (I don't believe it's true for `readonly`) is that changing the field's value constitutes an API change, even if you're just changing the value from `42` to `41`. The reason is that for `consts`, the value is determined during compile time, which means that if I compile a module that uses your constant, and you later change it, I will still be using the old value until I recompile my module with your new version.

Answer (score 2):

`readonly` is nice to use on things that can only be changed in your constructor. Examples of this is typical services as interfaces when you are following the TDD pattern.

In your example `const` is best, it's a constant after all.

[readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)

[const](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage for me is with `readonly` you are allowed to declare it anywhere in your code. But, you will get a chance to set it only **once**. With the setter, you declare and set in one stroke.

Comment: declare and set in one stroke?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first line making something constant or rather readonly using readonly keyword.

and the second line is making use of a property to implement readonly. Both do the same but if you compare with the IL the property would add few extra lines of code to the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a difference between the two.

A `readonly` field can only be set in the constructor.

A `{get; private set;}` can be set *at anytime* from within the class.

**Example:**

```
public class Car
{
    public readonly string Name;

    public string color {get; private set;}

    public Car()
    {
        Name = "Car";
        Color = "Red";
    }

    // will fail compilation
    public void ModifyName()
    {
        Name = "Subaru"
    }

    // perfectly ok
    public void ModifyColor()
    {
        Color = "Green"
    }
}
```

Comment: `{ get; private set; }` and `{get;}` are not the same thing. `{get; private set;}` means that the property is settable from within the class, but not outside. `{get;}` means that the property it settable _only from the constructor_. It can not be changed by other methods in the class. It is effectively a "read-only" property.

Comment: @Llama I've modified my answer to remove the erroneous section

Answer (score -1):

A Property is just *syntactic sugar* around a field, a property without a setter is simply declared a **readonly** field so the compiler will allow you to set it at **runtime** in the constructor, because to the compiler you are referencing a **readonly** field. There is a larger discussion around what to use a field or property, which is not within the scope of the question. And yes its this *syntactic sugar* that you have to do the recompiling referenced by @SOreadytohelp. Just to be clear a property is a field with a get and set method created for it, C# will allow you to reference it *like* a field rather than doing an annoying call to the getter or setter everytime.

Comment: How can I improve the answer so that I am more clear?

Comment: You use the terms "field" and "property" as if they aren't the same thing.

Comment: Also, this sentence doesn't make sense: "There is a larger discussion around what to use a field or property, which is not within the scope of the question."

Comment: @KolobCanyon A field is not a property, a field is just data that belongs to the object or class, a property is fundamentally a getter setter. As I said its just syntactic sugar around a field (data). There is no data associated with a property as its bare bones just a wrapper typically around a field (though this does not have to be so).